# Using GET in PowerShell & Exporting JSON to CSV

Tags: powershell, rest, csv, curl, get

I'm using the following CURL command, to read/fetch table data from an API:

```
curl -X GET \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer *myAccessToken*' \
    https://www.myWebsite.com/api/orders
```

This command/API Call returns a table in JSON format. I need to do two things with this.

[1] I need to run this in powershell. I've tried using the above code, and returns a general syntax error:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'X'.
```

[2] In PowerShell, Have the JSON output converted & saved as a CSV file

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-RestMethod` Cmdlet to Sends an [HTTP or HTTPS request to a RESTful web service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2)

```
$uri = "https://www.myWebsite.com/api/orders"
$headers = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    'Authorization' = 'Bearer <AccessToken>'
    'Accept'= 'application/json'
}
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers
```

[PowerShell formats the response based to the data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2#description). For JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) or XML, PowerShell converts, or deserializes, the content into `[PSCustomObject]` objects. So you can select the columns you want to export and pipe it into `Export-Csv` Cmdlet

```
$response | Select ColumnName1,ColumnName2 | Export-Csv -Path "filename.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul ! I'm getting a syntax error. Should the 'accept': be 'accept'= ?
(equals sign, not colon) ?

Comment: @DepthofField It should be `=`. Edited the answer!

Comment: Okay, and to have it export as CSV - Do I just add the export-CSV syntax as an additional line?

Comment: @DepthofField Yes!

Comment: Nothing is displayed on the screen when I use  "$response = Invoke-RestMethod " HOWEVER if remove $response so that it it's just "Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $headers -Body $body" - It displays the content! How can I tie the Export-CSV into this? THANKS!

Comment: In the first case nothing will be displayed because you are storing into `$response`

Comment: Ah, okay! How would I re-write the syntax so that it stores the data in $response and exports it as CSV? I inputted a couple of actual column names, but exports blank CSV files.